# Have to create web page that have to comfortable with web page view & mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just like to create a web page that means html & css code that have to comfortable with wab page and mobile view.. for that i are the technical i have to use.. just give some demos for about that?

Comment: make sure that for height and width you enter it in terms of %.Not in PX

Comment: i prefer using css media for making it responsive `@media all and (max-width: 699px) ...`

Comment: If you are using some images then try to use images of good pixels & agree with @ EnterJQ that u should use % not PX . For example you have a textbox then use like this <input type = "text" id = "textBox1" width = "40%" top = "30%" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following link:

[Twitter Bootstrap Github fluid site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html#)

This is example site which you are looking.